# reverse functionality of highcharts legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was wondering if there was any way to change the functionality of the legend shown in the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

For this example, is it possible that when you click "John", that is the option that is picked and all of the other options are not selected.

[image]

right now if you click "John", it deselects that option. So I basically want to reverse the default functionality of it now.

Also would it be possible to add a "Show All" option at the end of the legend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a "Show All" option at the end of the legend you could add an empty series with that name, like this:

```
series: [{
    // ...
}, { 
    name: 'Show All' 
}]
```

And then to reverse the legend functionality you can use the `legendItemClick` event, along with checking for clicks on your dummy series, for example like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
                var s = this.chart.series;
                for(i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    if(this.name == 'Show All' || this == s[i])
                        s[i].setVisible(true);
                    else
                        s[i].setVisible(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tpd03gxj/) using your initial demo.

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you